# React Hooks: Get innerHTML

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm build a questionnaire that has many input fields. At the bottom is a paragraph where the user inputs are filled into a paragraph:

```
function App() {
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  const [ food, setFood ] = useState('')

  const logText = () => {
    // This doesn't work but you get the idea
    console.log(divRef.current.innerHTML)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
      <input onChange={e => setFood(e.target.value)} value={food} />

      <div ref={divRef}>I want to eat {food}</div>

      <button onClick={logText}>Log Text!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I click the button I want to display the text in the ref to my terminal. I see that **divRef.current** gives me access to that element but none of the child properties on **current** seem to exist (divRef.current.innerText, divRef.current.innerHTML, divRef.current.value, etc).

Comment: When `logText` method is called then you need to set the value inside `setFood`

Comment: It gets set when the user types in the input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try don't work with DOM, work with data - this is React way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const MyForm = () => {
        const [food, setFood] = React.useState('');  
        const formatStatus = () => {
          return `I want to eat ${food}`
        }
        const handleChange = (e) => {
          setFood(e.target.value);
        }
        const logText = () => {
          console.log(formatStatus(food));
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <input onChange={handleChange} value={food} />
            <div>{formatStatus(food)}</div>
            <button onClick={logText}>Log Text!</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
      const App = () => {
        return (
          <MyForm/>
        );
      };
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to have a function that generates the text outside of the JSX. I can easily produce the text in the JSX and **logText** function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to get inner html, when the users type something on the input, the value of food can be updated by calling the onChange prop, this way you can console log directly value of food.

Here is the code

```js
function App() {
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  const [ food, setFood ] = useState('')


  const logText = () => {
    console.log(food)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
      <input value={food} onChange={e => setFood(e.target.value)}/>

      <div ref={divRef}>I wanto to eat {food}</div>

      <button onClick={logText}>Log Text!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Besides when the form is submit you can have acess to all input values from the event, **this way you dont need to create an variable to carry the value of every input**

Here is an example

```js
function App() {

  function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault() //to not reload the page
    console.log(event) // acess to all event props
    // event.target[0].value  - will gives you the value of the firt input ...

}

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      
      <input type="text"/>

      <button type="submit">Submit all values</button>
    </form >
  )
}
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Right, I already had the onChange prop on the input. You now have it typed twice in your code. My issue is I'm keep track of ~30 inputs and I don't want the giant paragraph typed twice.

Comment: Right, sorry! You can have acess to all values from a form by the submit event, when the form is submited a function is call, this function will receives a event as parameter this event will have a target parameter (the form it self) and by the form you can acess all the input - an array - and which input has their own value. I will edit my response adding examples of this

Comment: Ah gotcha, didn't know that about forms. Though, you're getting rid of the paragraph that I'm creating for the user as they fill out the input. I don't want to just collect the inputs and rebuild all the text again. Someone suggested a function that returns the paragraph I want. That was I can display it in the JSX and have access to it in **logText**.  Thanks though!

Comment: Got it! You´re welcome! I know that the other guy already gave you a solution, but in case you need someday, the event form that a mentioned can also be triggled using onChange on the form element (like: onChange={event => // event with all form props ...}), by that you can have acess values from all the inputs before they are submited. Thanks for your time :)